# Constructing a Turing Machine that deletes every second input symbol and then merges remaining string into a string with no blank gaps

Tags: logic, state-machine, automata, computation-theory, turing-machines

- Example input: 010101, output: 000
- Example input: 10011, output: 101
- Example input: 11101101, output: 1110

While drawing a state diagram for this problem, I am confused by how to merge the input symbols. I have seen others demonstrate how to concatenate when the alphabet consists of one symbol, however, in my case, I have to check if I am copying either a 1 or 0 to the left while removing gaps.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here, there is mention of a multi tape turing machine but it only partly explains how a solution may exist for my problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitape_Turing_machine#Two-stack_Turing_machine

Comment: this doesn't seem like an Answer, but an extension of your Question

Comment: unfortunately so. I was considering this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RtP4HM9mgj4 however the example assumes the blanks are in a single block as opposed to my own where this is not the case

Comment: This section is for answers. If you want to add clarifying information or other details regarding your question, please edit the question itself and include the text there.